# What does a topaz's "Melee Attackers take x damage per hit" modifier do?

Tags: diablo-iii

I noticed that the topaz has a modifier when socketed into a weapon that reads ***Melee attackers take x damage per hit***

What exactly does this mean?  Does it mean that I take the damage when using melee attacks or that opponents who attack me with melee attacks take damage (ala Thorns)?

Comment: I'm thinking it's like thorns, otherwise wouldn't it be more straight forward with "+x melee damage"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a thorns effect. Every time you're hit by a melee attack, the offending servant of darkness will take X damage as a rebuke for daring to strike your most august personage.

In fact, if you look at the detailed breakdown of your defenses in your character sheet, it's even *listed* as 'Thorns' there.

Comment: 800 means nothing in inferno. Totally useless stats?

Comment: I understand. Does this help buff Mantra of Retribution at all? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This would be just like thorns; if a monster attacks you from melee range, they would take the damage listed.  If you have more than one item with this property, they will accumulate to provide a set amount of damage whenever you get hit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is [like Thorns](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4768357189).

> Note that it says "attackERS" not "attacks" .. meaning it is a reflect damage of sorts.

Comment: If I attack I am an attackER.  If I am attacked, I am attacked by an attackER.  Yes?

Comment: It's a quote, not my wording.  The link provides a discussion that in context explains that it is like Thorns, and many posters specifically mention that it is like Thorns.  Also, I don't believe the game ever refers to you as an attacker for personal abilities.  Personal abilities - **attacks**, effects on others (allies and enemies) - **attackers**.